# Does Survivor NPC's equipment degrade?

Tags: state-of-decay

Does the equipment used by NPC survivors in *State of Decay* degrade with usage, or is that only for the current player character?

Answer (score 1):

Only equipment equipped by player-controlled characters will degrade. On the same note, only player-controlled character will earn exp in combat and missions.